# How can i get the exact coodrdinates of an element in Selenium

Tags: selenium, location, coordinates, element

I want to get the X and Y coordinates of an element available in the webpage.I used getLocation() , getX(), getY() functions. But as they give the relative location; it didnt work well with my scenario.

Can someone please suggest me an option to get the exact location

thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your screen and screen resolution, as well as where your Chrome window is. So a relatively easy solution would be to full screen your Chrome using something like `SendKeys(Keys.F11)`. Then, use the `getLocation` which now would be the exact on the screen.

Comment: But... would it affect when im using the same selenium script in different resolution monitors ?

Comment: It depends on what your scenario exactly is, but generally if you're only using the coordinates to interact with the elements while they're on screen then it won't affect and should work.